# Is axios the correct method to fetch data for Next.js

Tags: next.js

I am using axios get method to display data on my website
but it takes too much time.

Every time I load my website first all the html components are being shown after that only the data is shown.

Which is not good for my website what should I do to fix that

```
import React from "react";
import Alert from "react-bootstrap/Alert";
import axios from "axios";
import { useState } from "react";
import { useEffect } from "react";
import Link from "next/link";
// import Head from "next/head";

export default function Question() {
  const [Items, setItems] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get("https://ask-over.herokuapp.com/questapi").then((result) => {
      // console.table(result.data);
      setItems(result.data);
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      {/* {console.log(Items)} */}
      {Items.reverse().map((itm, k) => (
        <Link
          key={itm._id}
          href={{
            pathname: "query/[itm]"
            // query: { id: itm.id },
          }}
          as={`query/${encodeURIComponent(itm._id)}`}
        >
          {/* <Link href={`/query/${encodeURIComponent(itm._id)}`}> */}

          <Alert className="question13">{itm.Name}</Alert>
        </Link>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Why don't you pre-render the page (either SSG or SSR) with the data? That's what Next.js is useful for. See https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/pages#pre-rendering for details.

Answer (score 0):

I think is more about workflow

> useEffect(() => {
> axios.get("https://ask-over.herokuapp.com/questapi").then((result) => {
> // console.table(result.data);
> setItems(result.data);
> });   }, []);

This is only executed once you "initialize" the component.

A workaround for you problem would be using a state manager like Redux and call the api all the info you can on the beginning of the app  and instead of

> const [Items, setItems] = useState([]);

you would use something like

> const Items = useSelector((state) => state.itemsReducer.data); //Accessing the state of Redux

Adding Redux to the project will require some additional setting up.

More info on https://redux.js.org/introduction/getting-started

Note: If you really need to get info as you interact with the app you may be bound to this kind of problem.

Answer (score 0):

> Every time I load my website first all the html components are being shown after that only the data is shown.

You could take another loading state for your website. like, 
`const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);`

Not inside your `.then` if your API call is successful then simply do
`setLoading(false)` and at the end of your logic and before your return block add this condition.

```
if(loading) {
    return <p>Loading...</p>
}
```

This won't load your HTML first.